# using both AttributeRoutes and MapRoute for Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

So I have different Areas in my MVC application, and I want to define some of their routes using Attributes and some other ones with `MapRoute`:

Here's what is RouteConfig file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Dashboard_route",
        url: "Dashboard/{action}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index"}
    );
}
```

When I use Attributes (`[RouteArea("someRoute")]` and `[Route]`) everything is fine, but when it comes to `MapRoute`, the controllers couldn't find my Views folder under Areas Directory and I am getting this error:
The view 'getdashboard' or its master was not found or no view engine supports

```
the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Dashboard/getdashboard.aspx
~/Views/Dashboard/getdashboard.ascx
~/Views/Shared/getdashboard.aspx
~/Views/Shared/getdashboard.ascx
~/Views/Dashboard/getdashboard.cshtml
~/Views/Dashboard/getdashboard.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/getdashboard.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/getdashboard.vbhtml
```

Is there anyway to define the Views directory using MapRoute?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you create an Area there is an `AreaRegistration` class inside of the `/Areas/<Area Name>/` directory where you register its routes.

```
public class TestAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And then from your `Application_Start()` method, you need to ensure you call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` so this registration code gets executed.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

Once it is set up that way, it looks for the views in the `/Areas/<Area Name>/Views/` directory.